# My comparator isn't sorting this PriorityQueue correctly?

Tags: java, comparator

It's my understanding that I don't need to use any methods to sort a [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), but merely adding items to it and fetching items leaves them in a natural order.

**Queue**

```
public class JobSetQueue extends PriorityBlockingQueue<JobSet> {
    public JobSetQueue() {
        super(1, new JobSetComparator());
    }
}
```

**Comparator**

I've stepped through the debugger to verify that the getValue() methods below are returning the expected values for the highest priority and the proper value is returned that the Comparator is expecting.  Am I wrong?  **is there something I need to do in order to have the comprator affect the PriorityQueue order?**

```
public class JobSetComparator implements Comparator<JobSet> {

    @Override
    public int compare(JobSet o1, JobSet o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.getHighestPriority().getValue(), o2.getHighestPriority().getValue());
    }
}
```

**Priority**

```
public class Priority {
    public static final Priority TOP = new Priority("TOP", 1000);

    public static final Priority PRIORITY_REMAN = new Priority("PRIORITY_REMAN", 750);

    public static final Priority PRIORITY = new Priority("PRIORITY", 500);

    public static final Priority STANDARD_REMAN = new Priority("STANDARD_REMAN", 250);

    public static final Priority STANDARD = new Priority("STANDARD", 100);

    private final String name;
    private final int value;

    protected Priority(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

**My test**:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    queue = new JobSetQueue();

    queue.add(new JobSet(new JobUnit(new Product(new ProductEntity(), Priority.STANDARD), 1)));
    queue.add(new JobSet(new JobUnit(new Product(new ProductEntity(), Priority.PRIORITY_REMAN), 1)));
    queue.add(new JobSet(new JobUnit(new Product(new ProductEntity(), Priority.PRIORITY), 1)));
}

@Test
public void testTop() {
    queue.add(new JobSet(new JobUnit(new Product(new ProductEntity(), Priority.TOP), 1)));

    Assert.assertEquals("Queue priority,", Priority.TOP, queue.poll().getJobUnitList().get(0).getProduct().getPriority());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't see Integer.compare in the Javadoc, I see compareTo.

Second of all, I think your comparator is backward. You want the highest priority to come before a smaller one :

```
 @Override
    public int compare(JobSet o1, JobSet o2) {
        return o2.getHighestPriority().getValue() - o1.getHighestPriority().getValue());
    }
```

Here you will return a negative number if 01's priority is higher (ie if o1 is less than 02 to come before it in the queue).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the javadoc for Java 6. My mistake

Comment: No. compareTo(a, b) should essentially return a-b. In any case calling another compare() method with the same arguments in the same order can't be wrong.

Comment: In fairness, a numeric comparator should only return a-b if it can be guaranteed that there will be no subtraction overflow. While that may be the case here, others reading this thread may conclude incorrectly that the same can be used in general.

Comment: @vtheron - Integer.compare() is equivalant to what you put there.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int, int)

Comment: Of course `.poll()` gives me the least of the items... so I changed the priority values so that the top priority is a lower number.

Comment: @Webnet from the doc : Returns:
the value 0 if x == y; a value less than 0 if x < y; and a value greater than 0 if x > y. For this situation, a high priority has to come first, so we want a value less than 0 if x > y.

Comment: Note to all the comments : no, compare doesn't do the same thing. Here 01 has to come first (ie be less than o2) if it's value is greater.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are expecting the iterator of the PQ to iterate in order. It doesn't. See the Javadoc. Ordering of a PQ is only observable on removal.

Comment: You are correct that the iterator interface implemented by PriorityQueue doesn't iterate in prioritized order but its not relevant because the code in the quesion is using [poll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#poll()) which removed the head of the queue and will respect the priorities.